Meaning of 小路を曲折する
From Kokoro chapter 20:

帰る時、奥さんは「どうもお気の毒さま」と会釈した。その調子は忙しいところを暇を潰させて気の毒だというよりも、せっかく来たのに泥棒がはいらなくって気の毒だという冗談のように聞こえた。奥さんはそういいながら、先刻出した西洋菓子の残りを、紙に包んで私の手に持たせた。私はそれを袂へ入れて、人通りの少ない夜寒の小路を曲折して賑やかな町の方へ急いだ。

I am not certain with 人通りの少ない夜寒の小路を曲折して part. I found a relevant definition from here that reads「曲がりくねること。折れ曲がること。「人通りの少ない夜寒の小路を—して」〈漱石・こゝろ〉」. I think 小路を曲折する means to walk in zig-zag manner on 小路 like a drunkard?

No, it does not mean the protagonist can't walk straight. It simply means he made several turns along the alley. Small roads inherently have many intersections and corners, and it's impossible to keep walking straight without bumping into the walls of other people's houses.
